# jQuery alternative to $.each

Tags: jquery, each

I found that the $.each is very slow and makes problems to the web pages if containing lot of various jQuery effects.

I'd like to know if there is a good alternative to the $.each, for example:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
   var singleLi = $(this);
});
```

without the hover, how can I do the same without using each?

Thanks.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: I call into question the claim that "$.each()" itself is a cause of performance problems. It isn't at all, in my opinion and experience, except for some extreme performance situations which by definition would not involve "lots of various jQuery effects". You should post an example of what you consider a problem, and then we can help figure out the **real** problem.

Comment: $.each is slow. If you use it for massive data is very slow.

Comment: No, @Toro, it really is not that slow. Yes, it's slower than a "for" loop, but esp. in modern JavaScript runtimes the overhead isn't that great. In your example, for instance, how many `<li>` elements to you have?  If there are thousands and thousands of them, then the problem is that your DOM is very large, not that "$.each()" is slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly the same way without `each`

```
$('#list li').hover(function() {
        $('#myDiv').stop().fadeIn(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#myDiv').stop().fadeOut(400);
    })
});
```

Comment: the `stop()` will ensure that both effects don't overlap.

Comment: Although, you may want to use `.stop(true, true)`, otherwise, they do just that stop and never finish the animation and your stuck with a half-faded div.

Comment: need stop(true, true)... or it doesn't work. But my Question is different.

Comment: Note that the code for the ".hover()" method will perform a ".each()" internally anyway ...

Comment: Up voted because of the introduction to the .stop() method, as I've always wondered if there was a way to prevent multiple triggers of jQuery effects that run until fully iterated through.  I suspect `.stop()` will stop them from doing that.

Answer (score 25):

If you want an actual **alternative** to "$.each()", just use a "for" loop:

```
var liElements = $('ul li');
for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; ++i) {
  var li = liElements[i];
  // ... lots of various jQuery effects ...
}
```

The suggestions that you can skip ".each()" and just use ".hover()" directly are correct, but they miss the point: those jQuery routines will perform a ".each()" internally anyway.

I doubt that switching from "$.each()" to the "for" loop will all by itself make much of a difference, however.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You can get benchmarks comparing the  performance of $.each vs other looping methods here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/4

Comment: I tried this instead of $.get, mainly because it was giving me an error with $.get. So it worked perfect. I highly recommend for cycle instead of $.get().

Answer (score 3):

yes... just add the hover to all li's

```
$('#list li').hover(function() {
    $('#myDiv').fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('#myDiv').fadeOut(400);
});

$('#myDiv').fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an ID has to be unique, that whole script should not alter if the `.each()` is removed.

`$.hover()` does not mean much.

```
$('#list li').hover(function() {
    $('#myDiv').fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('#myDiv').fadeOut(400);
});

$('#myDiv').fadeOut(400);
```